# How do I deal with BTRFS raid1 when usb disk device mappings changes?

Tags: linux, raid, mount, storage, btrfs

I created a btrfs raid1 one by using "mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdg1". It worked fine but next time I restarted my pc it seemed like the sdg device became sdf therefor btrfs refused to mount this raid1.

Is there a way to create this btrfs raid1 without using device mappings?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to mount the filesystem using its [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) rather than the partition name.

To find the UUID of /dev/sdf1 use the `blkid` command or:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdf1
```

You should see that both partitions in your BTRFS RAID1 device have the same UUID.  Now you can mount it like so:

```
mount -U uuid /mountpoint
```

and add it to `/etc/fstab` so it is mounted at boot:

```
UUID=uuid /mountpoint btrfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is not BTRFS-specific. The problem can and does affect any filesystem, and mounting by UUID is the correct solution in all cases.